# MInified CSS file isn't loaded on a page where I have a webform with the "file upload" component

Tags: 8

I added a webform with the *Upload file* component on a page.
When I visit that page without minifying CSS files, everything works fine; when CSS files are minified, this page doesn't load them, the page seems a WSOD. The other pages work fine.

When I remove the *Upload file* component, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar situation (though I can't remember if it was for all pages or a subset of pages). For me, the issue was with one css include in my custom theme. (I think my issue might have been that the css file was a mix of minified and unminified css - I don't know why that was the case - but I never got to the bottom of it.)

My workaround solution was to prevent the one css file from being aggregated. To do this, you can set `preprocess: false` for the css file. See the [Library options and details documentation on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195#libraries-options-details).

My library ended up looking something like:

```
my_library:
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/app.css: { preprocess: false }
      assets/css/theme.css: { }
  js:
    'assets/js/app.js': { }
    'assets/js/theme.js': { }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

which allows all of my theme's files to be aggregated except for app.css.

---

To debug this issue, I did roughly the following:

1. Tested with a different theme, e.g. bartik or your base theme (to determine where the issue is)
2. Once I verified that my theme was the issue, I first excluded all items from aggregation (using `preprocess: false`).
3. Once I verified that pages loaded fine with none of my theme's files aggregated, I re-enabled aggregation for them one by one.